# XAML WPF Checkbox doesn´t visualize when .ischecked property changed

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox

I´m a beginner in WPF and XAML Programming. And my English isn't very good. Sorry for that!

Here is my Problem. I want a custom Check-box. It should only be enabled when the Mouse is over and the Cursor should change to the Help-Cursor.

That works fine! When i click in the Check-box, the Check-box changes to `.ischeckd = true` and shows the litte arrow in the check-box. When i click again in the check-box the `.ischecked` property changes to `false` an the little arrow in the Check-box is gone. So far so good!
But when I set the .ischeckd Value Programaticaly it doesn't changes the little arrow in the Check-box. So the User of the Program thinks the Check-box is "active" even though the .ischecked property is false. Hope you understand my Problem...
Here is the XAML Code:

```
</Style>
    <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardCheckBox"/>
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,42,0">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsEnabled)" Storyboard.TargetName="checkBox">
                                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="Gutschrift" FontSize="13.333" IsEnabled="False" Cursor="Help" Margin="0,0,4.937,0"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content="" Margin="78.063,9.723,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

...
some lables and buttons and other stuff

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="29,0,0,44" Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="125" Name="CheckBoxGutschrift" IsChecked="False" DataContext="{Binding}" Checked="CheckBoxGutschrift_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBoxGutschrift_Unchecked" ClickMode="Press" IsTabStop="False" />
```

Hope you understand my Problem! Thanks a lot for the answers, Ruediger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to bind internal checkbox's `IsChecked` property in the control template:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" ...
```